# how to play videos in viewpager2 from firebase like tiktok , instagram reels do?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, video-streaming, android-viewpager2

[fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu9PQ.png)

[adapter class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYufB.png)

As you can see in the calling adapter from fragment . Here, a videoview is set with a firebase storage video link, but when the videoview is swapped with viewpager2, it, Buffering,  I want to play videos like tiktok and instagram reel do.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. Besides that, what exactly in that code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: you can see images by just clicking of there name below the question.